# Taking Limits of Sets

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series, solution-verification

I know this sounds like a ridiculous idea- but it's the only one I can think of for this radius of convergence problem for a power series involving sine.

I want to let $P:= \{k:|sin(k)| \geq \delta  ,     k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $0\leq\delta\leq \frac{1}{2} $
As we make $\delta$ smaller and smaller we will obviously reach the set $P:={\mathbb{N}}$ so I want to take the limit of $P$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0 $

If the context of the problem is needed in more detail or what my actual plan of attack is I will post it in an edit.

### EDIT:

Here is the question:

a)
Show that there exists a sequence of integers $(n_r)$ such that $n_r \rightarrow \infty$   as $r \rightarrow \infty$
and $sin(n_r) \geq \frac{1}{2}$

I am  fine with part a)-please let's not discuss for fear of digression.

b) Find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 sin(k) x^k}{6^k}$

Let's call this roc $R$
Now $0 \leq \frac{k^3 |sin(k)| x^k}{6^k} \leq \frac{k^3 x^k}{6^k}$

Apply the Ratio Test to to $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^3  x^k}{6^k}$- we get a radius of convergence of 6 so $\forall x : |x| \leq 6 $ this sum converges 
and so by the comparision test  $\forall x : |x| \leq 6 $ $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 |sin(k)| x^k}{6^k}$ converges. But absolute convergence implies convergence so $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 sin(k) x^k}{6^k}$ converges. But all this tells us is that $R \geq 6$ which is no good. I suspect that R=6. So if we can show there is something less than $\frac{k^3 sin(k) x^k}{6^k}$ with roc $=6$ then we can say now also $R \leq 6$ by comparision test and so R=6. This failed.

So I thought maybe use part a) That must have been included for a reason.

Let $P:= \{k:|sin(k)| \geq \frac{1}{2}  ,     k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ (we could have have shown also there was a sequence $n_r : sin(n_r) \leq -\frac{1}{2}$ so this is fine)

Now $0 \leq \frac{k^3 (\frac{1}{2}) x^k}{6^k}\leq \frac{m^3 |sin(m)| x^m}{6^m}\leq \frac{k^3 x^k}{6^k} $ where $m$ is the $k- th $ element of $P$

Please stop here for now.

CONFUSION: When I use the comparison test for a series- I must compare TERM BY TERM right? The set which the index belongs to matters right? The $k$ or the $n$ is just a dummy variable right? e.g  take $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$ $\sum\limits_{k=p} \frac{1}{k^2}$ where $p$ is prime
You must take the first number in the set of natural numbers for first series and the first number in the set of primes? so $\frac{1}{1^2} \geq \frac{1}{2^2}$

$\frac{1}{2^2} \geq \frac{1}{3^2}$

$\frac{1}{3^2} \geq \frac{1}{5^2}$

$\frac{1}{4^2} \geq \frac{1}{7^2}$

Inductively the $k-th$ prime $\geq k$ so $\frac{1}{m^2} \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ where $m$ is the $k-th$ prime and now you can use Comparison Test. If this is correct way to use comparison test with same $f(k)$ but summation index not equal- it's back to the problem.

It should be clear now that $\sum\limits_{k}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 sin(k) x^k}{6^k}$ has radius of convergence exactly 6 now when we use ratio and comparision test on the the 3 term inequality we stopped at before the digression.

But now my point is there is nothing special about $\frac{1}{2}$: we can let $\delta$ tend to $0$ and the set $P$ covers all numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ in which case the $\sum\limits_{m \in P}^{\infty} \frac{m^3 |sin(m)| x^k}{6^m}$ becomes $\sum\limits_{k}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 |sin(k)| x^k}{6^k}$ . We also cannot let $\delta=0$ otherwise $\frac{k^3 (\delta) x^k}{6^k}$ becomes $0$ and we lose the important lower bound which is the main bit telling us the radius of convergence $R$ is $\leq 6$ which combined with upper bound in comparison test $R \geq 6$ gives us $R=6$ . (Though if you think about it by definition of radius of convergence- you dont even need the upper bound of $\frac{k^3 x^k}{6^k}$)

...so this is why I asked about limits of sets...

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Can't this just be looked at and evaluated directly? $\{k : \lvert\sin{k}\rvert \geq 0, k \in \mathbb{N}\}=\mathbb{N}$. Why do you need this concept of a limit?

Comment: Call your set $P_\delta$. I suppose you could write $\displaystyle\bigcup_{0<\delta\le1/2}P_\delta$, which should equal $\mathbb N$. (I think you wanted $0<\delta$ rather than $0\le\delta$, since $P_0=\mathbb N$.)

Comment: Often, when you want to take the "limit" of sets, it suffices to just take the union or intersection. For example, let's say we have:$$A_0\subseteq A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq\dotsb$$It makes sense to define the "limit" to be:$$A_\omega:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$$(If we had $A_0\supseteq\dotsb$, the "limit" should be the intersection instead of union.)

Comment: @MichaelGaluza bear with me I will type

Comment: @DivergentQueries I cannot look at $\delta =0$ directly I want to use the comparision test for convergence of series and using $\delta=0$ will give me a useless bound of infinity. So I must take the limit

Comment: @Arcane1729: Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: "The limit of sets" is an interesting idea. You could say $S$ is the limit of the set-valued function $S_{\delta}$ as $\delta \rightarrow c$ to be such that for every element $s$ of $S$, there is some $\epsilon$ such that for all $\delta$ with $|\delta - c| < \epsilon$, $s \in S_{\delta}$ and each $S_{\delta} \subset S$. This would admit $\mathbb{N}$ as the limit of your set.

Comment: @ColmBhandal: That's usually not a good definition. For example when we want to have multi-valued functions it is far more useful to have **uniform** convergence rather than pointwise convergence.

Comment: @user21820 I take your word for it but I would need to see a concrete example to emotionally convince myself.

Comment: @ColmBhandal: Say we have continuous multi-valued functions $f,g$. Then $f(g(S+D)) \to f(g(S))$ as $D \to \{0\}$. This would not work if limits aren't defined to be uniform (I think), but certainly works if they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\lvert x \rvert > 6$.
If $n$ is a positive integer such that $\lvert \sin(n) \rvert \ge 1/2$, we have
$$
\left\lvert \frac{n^3 sin(n) x^n}{6^n} \right\rvert \ge \lvert\sin(n)\rvert\left\lvert\frac{x}{6}\right\rvert^n > \frac{1}{2}
$$
Since there are infinitely many such $n$, this inequality shows that $\frac{k^3 sin(k) x^k}{6^k}$ does not tend to $0$ as $k \to \infty$, which means that the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 sin(k) x^k}{6^k}$ is divergent. This implies $R \le 6$ as desired.

Comment: did you forget an $n^3$ in that second line? so it becomes a $\frac{1}{2}n^3$ which tends to infinity?

Comment: Ah I understand now, fantastic, thanks