# Help with Set Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I asked an odd question about the concept of limits of sets in another post ([Taking Limits of Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397180/taking-limits-of-sets?noredirect=1)-) but it got rather convoluted and I thought I could split it up into sub parts of the problem and put each into different posts:

**Edit: Forget about limits of sets- how do I solve the problem in relation to Statement A and the set P**

I have a Statement $A$ relating to something about the sequence $\sin(k), k \in \mathbb{N}$. I have to show that it is true for the whole of $\mathbb{N}$ but I've realised I'm going to have to find a clever way around it.
I want to let $P:= \{k:|\sin(k)| \geq \delta  ,     k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $0<\delta\leq \frac{1}{2} $

Pick any $\delta$ in this range. Statement $A$ will be true for the set $P$
Intuitively though one can see that it must be true for the set $\mathbb{N}$
As we make $\delta$ smaller and smaller we will obviously reach the set $P:={\mathbb{N}}$ so I want to take the limit of $P$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0 $

If you see my idea please can you tell me how can I make this rigorous. If you need the context- please click the link- its an Analysis Problem. 
($\delta$ cannot equal $0$ by the way or I wouldnt wasting time with this)

Answer (score 1):

You have a function from positive reals to sets, $F$, given by $F(\delta)=\{k\in\mathbb{N}: \vert \sin(k)\vert\ge \delta\}.$ Moreover, $F$ is *monotonic*: if $\delta_0\le \delta_1$ then $F(\delta_0)\supseteq F(\delta_1)$. This means there is a very natural notion of limit: for $a$ a non-negative real, the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the right is $$\{k: \exists b>a(k\in F(b))\}.$$ In the case $a=0$, which is what you are interested in, with $a=0$, this gives the limit $\{1, 2, 3, . . .\}$; depending on whether you count $0$ as a natural number, this either is or isn't the whole of $\mathbb{N}$. (I *do*, so I would say this *isn't*.)

Note that your function $F$ is not *continuous*: if we let $\delta=\sin(2)$, for instance, then the limit of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches $\delta$ from the right is $\{3, 4, 5, . . .\}$, but $F(\delta)=\{2, 3, 4, 5, . . . \}$.

(Note also that the monotonicity of $F$ is absolutely crucial: for an arbitrary map from positive reals to sets, it's totally unclear how to define the limit of that map.)

---

Glancing also at your original question, I'm still unclear what your motivation for looking at this limit is; if you can clarify that, maybe there is more that can be said that you would find useful.

Comment: it is in the other post in full detail